# Regarding ConcurrentHashMap, what does the following mean?

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency

Directly from the [ConcurrentHashMap javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> The allowed concurrency among update operations is guided by the
>   optional concurrencyLevel constructor argument (default 16), which is
>   used as a hint for internal sizing. The table is internally
>   partitioned to try to permit the indicated number of concurrent
>   updates without contention. Because placement in hash tables is
>   essentially random, the actual concurrency will vary.

I do not get the point when they say: "which is used as a hint for internal sizing". Should not the sizing be determing by the capacity and not by the concurrencyLevel?

Comment: I guess that they mean the that it serves as a hint for the number of partitions (or segments), and not for the number of buckets in the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the table is internally partitioned - this means they divide up the table into ConcurrencyLevel divisions in the hopes that they can do that many concurrent updates without any collisions.

there is no guarantee however that the hashed data will fall nicely in those partitions.

Comment: Actually, as the question says, it's a hint, and not an absolute value. The actual number of partitions is derived from this level.

Comment: So there is a strict relation between the capacity and the concurrencyLevel right? that's perhaps why the default values are the 16 16 0.75(load factor).

Comment: No, there is no strict relation. Why do you think there is? The capacity will simply be splitted into the number of partitions.

Comment: And what if the capacity is less then the concurrencyLevel?

Comment: That's handled by the constructor. It guarantees that the capacity is at least 2 for every partition. Note that I can answer to these questions simply by looking at the source code, which is freely available. Why don't you look at it?

Comment: @JBNizet I think I will be looking to the source code and stop asking you further questions. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I'm happy to answer questions. Don't take it badly. Just wanted to inform you that the source code is available for free. A whole lot of people here aren't aware of that.

Comment: @JBNizet no issues at all man, just realized that you were right. I did not mean any sarcasm or whatsoever. Thanks again.